# Using getBoundingClientRect() for multiple elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add sticky navigation to my website that will change as it scrolls over different sections. When scrolling over a section with the class `.dark`, it should change the logo and text colour to white.. otherwise black.

The javascript I've been using is below but this only seems to apply to the first element with the class `.dark`, how can I adapt this to target all elements with the same class?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {

        var section = document.querySelector('.dark').getBoundingClientRect(),
            logo = document.querySelector('#logo-container').getBoundingClientRect();

          if (section.top <= logo.top + logo.height && section.top + section.height > logo.top) {
            document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.add('white-logo');
            document.getElementById('navholder').style.color = "#fff";

          } else {
            document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.remove('white-logo');
            document.getElementById('navholder').style.color = "#111";
          }

     });
```

I apologise if this is an obvious question, I'm not too knowledgeable when it comes to javascript! I've tried to look for a solution to this but have not had much success.. any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: `querySelector` only ever returns a maximum of _one_ element to begin with; you’d need to use `querySelectorAll` if you want to get all of them. But then of course you’d still have to _loop over_ them, and perform your checks for each one individually - “calling” getBoundingClientRect on multiple elements at the same time is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break this out into several functions, it makes life easier. You can check if the logo is is any of the sections, and then set its class accordingly:

```js
const setLogoBlackStatus = status => {
  if (status) {
    document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.add('black-logo');
    document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.remove('white-logo');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.add('white-logo');
    document.getElementById('logo-container').classList.remove('black-logo');
  }
}

const logoIsInSection = logo => sectionRect => sectionRect.top <= logo.top + logo.height &&
  sectionRect.top + sectionRect.height > logo.top

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  var sectionRects = [...document.querySelectorAll('.dark')]
    .map(el => el.getBoundingClientRect());

  var logo = document.querySelector('#logo-container').getBoundingClientRect();

  var logoInAnySections = sectionRects
    .some(logoIsInSection(logo))

  setLogoBlackStatus(!logoInAnySections);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vw;
  left: 20vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.white-logo {
  filter: invert(90%);
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 30);
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/cc.svg" id="logo-container"/>
<div class="section white"></div>
<div class="section dark"></div>
<div class="section white"></div>
<div class="section dark"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly!! I don't think I ever could have arrived at this so thank you :)

Comment: @David I'm sure you could have arrived at it in time, but it's good to save the time and ask in my opinion!